# If $\mu(E_n) < \infty$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $1_{E_n} \to f$ in $L^1$, then $f$ is a char. function of measurable set.

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem**: If $\mu(E_n) < \infty$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $1_{E_n} \to f$ in $L^1$, then $f$ is a char. function of a measurable set.

**Attempt**: Since $1_{E_n} \to f$ in $L^1$ , there is a subsequence $1_{E_{n_k}}$ that converges to $f$ a.e as $k \to \infty$.  Since characteristic functions take on two values $0$ and $1$, the image of $f$ is $0$ and $1$ a.e  in which case

$$f\equiv 1_{f^{-1}(1)}$$

a.e  and we know $f^{-1}(1)$ is measurable since $f \in L^1$.

My attempted solution is incorrect, since I don't use the fact that $\mu(E_n) < \infty$.  However, I don't see where my error is.  Can someone point it out?

Comment: The only reason you need $\mu(E_n) < \infty$ is so that $1_{E_n} \in L^1$.  Your proof is completely correct.

Answer (score 2):

The theorem you used, states that if a sequence $\{f_n\}$ from $L^1$ converges to $f$ in $L^1$, then there is a sub-sequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ that converges a.e to $f$. Now, the condition $\mu(E_n)<+\infty$ is equivalent to $1_{E_n}\in L^1$, So, you used this hypothesis  in your correct solution. A related  question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744916/needed-help-in-lebesgue-integral/744965#744965).